# JSON , перебрать данные , массив в массиве

Tags: fetch

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import "./crypto.css";

class Cryptocurrency extends Component {
    render () {    
        var {
            pair,
            bid
        } = this.props.data;
        var percent = (bid * 1.05).toFixed(2);
        //var rus = (percent * 57).toFixed(2);
    return (
        <div className={"cryptocurrency " + pair}>
            <h1>{percent}</h1>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

class Ticker extends Component {
    fetchCryptocurrencyData() {
        const endpoint = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD,tETHUSD,tXRPUSD,tBCHUSD,tLTCUSD,tNEOUSD';
        const myInit = { method: 'GET', mode: 'cors', cache: 'default'};

        fetch(endpoint, myInit)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json()})
            .then(function(response) {
                var wanted = ["tBTCUSD", "tETHUSD", "tXRPUSD", "tBCHUSD", "tLTCUSD", "tNEOUSD"];
                var result = response.filter(currency => wanted.includes(currency[0]));
                console.log(result)
            })
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        this.fetchCryptocurrencyData();
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.fetchCryptocurrencyData(), 120000);
    }
    state = {
        data: [
            {   
                pair: "tBTCUSD",
                bid: "1"
            },
            {
                pair: "tETHUSD",
                bid: "1"
            },
            {
                pair: "tXRPUSD",
                bid: "1"
            },
            {
                pair: "tBCHUSD",
                bid: "1"
            },
            {
                pair: "tLTCUSD",
                bid: "1"
            },
            {
                pair: "tNEOUSD",
                bid: "1"
            }
        ]
    }
    render() {
        var tickers = this.state.data.map((currency) => 
        <Cryptocurrency data={currency} key={currency.pair}/>
        )
        return (
            <div className="tickers-container">
                <div className='tickers'> {tickers} </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    componentWillUnmont() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
}

export default Ticker;
```

Помогите вытащить данные, есть json, состоит массив в массиве, нужно узнать есть ли в массиве ["tBTCUSD", "tETHUSD", "tXRPUSD", "tBCHUSD", "tLTCUSD", "tNEOUSD"], если есть вытащить index1(цены)...

data = [["tBTCUSD",8496.9],["tETHUSD",516.47,],["tXRPUSD",0.62782],["tBCHUSD",969.78,],["tLTCUSD",159.14],["tNEOUSD",64.112]]